# Restoring windows backup after the version of Windows has been changed

Tags: reinstall, windows-backup

I have created a Windows Backup of my C:\ and have it saved it in my D:. The backup was done by selecting the, "Let Windows Choose what files to backup" option. I am currently having Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit version. I want to ask that if I reinstall Windows to some other version, (say Vista or 8 or Windows 7 Ultimate), will I still be able to restore the files? Even if the files are restored, will there be any kind of problems or conflicts?

Comment: Do you mean "will I still be able to restore the files"

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, i will edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a restore CD so that you can boot and start recovery from the CD if you cannot boot from HD. You also need to check that Windows had enough space on your backup device to create a system image - if there was then you should be able to do a complete restore from the backup. If there was not enough space for the image just your data files would get backed up. However if you plan to start experimenting I would create another copy of key data on a portable hard drive.